# Prolog: Creating a frequency list of another list

Tags: prolog

So, I've written a program that reads input from a .txt file in the form of 2 integers and a list of integers: the first integer is the length of the list, the second is the number of different elements, and the list is the list in question.

I then want to create a list of frequencies for the elements, like so:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1],
FreqList = [3, 2, 3].
```

Here is my code:

```
% Create random list
createList(List) :-
length(List, 10), 
maplist(random(0,4), List).

% Count the frequency of an element:
countElement(_, [], 0) :- !.
countElement(_, [], _).
countElement(Element, [Element|Tail], Counter) :-
    countElement(Element, Tail, Counter2),
    Counter is Counter2 + 1.
countElement(Element, [_|Tail], Counter) :-
    countElement(Element, Tail, Counter).

% Create frequency list:
createFreqList(_, _, Numbers, [], CurrentNumber) :-
    Numbers = CurrentNumber.
createFreqList(List, Length, Numbers, [Head|Tail], CurrentNumber) :-
    Numbers \= CurrentNumber,
    countElement(CurrentNumber, List, Head),
    CurrentNumber2 is CurrentNumber + 1,
    createFreqList(List, Length, Numbers, Tail, CurrentNumber2).

frequency(List, FreqList) :-
    createList(List),
    Numbers2 is 4,
    createFreqList(List, 10, Numbers2, FreqList, 1).
```

So, on first execution the program runs ok, and it outputs the correct frequency list. However, if I input ';', instead of giving me 'false' it runs again, outputing a wrong frequency list, and that just repeats for as long as I press ';'.

Comment: This means there is a choice point that shouldn't be there, but I don't see how to run your code to debug it. If I had to guess, you need a cut at the end of the second clause of `countElement/3`.

Comment: @DanielLyons you are absolutely right, the snippet I posted is actually part of a bigger program, I was debugging and narrowed it down to this. However, I never posted the read_input rule or the structure of the .txt input, I edited the original question so that it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just in case you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

There is a quasi standard called library(aggregate). But library(aggregate) can be also implemented on top of the ISO core standard bagof/3, which also gets you there:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.6)

?- aggregate(count, member(X,[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]), R).
X = 1,
R = 3 ;
X = R, R = 2 ;
X = R, R = 3.

?- bagof(hit, member(X,[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]), L), length(L, R).
X = 1,
L = [hit, hit, hit],
R = 3 ;
X = R, R = 2,
L = [hit, hit] ;
X = R, R = 3,
L = [hit, hit, hit].
```

Or in another Prolog system:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.7 (May 23, 2019)

?- use_module(library(advanced/aggregate)).
% 3 consults and 0 unloads in 110 ms.
Yes

?- use_module(library(basic/lists)).
% 0 consults and 0 unloads in 0 ms.
Yes

?- aggregate(count, member(X,[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]), R).
X = 1,
R = 3 ;
X = 2,
R = 2 ;
X = 3,
R = 3

?- bagof(hit, member(X,[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]), L), length(L, R).
X = 1,
L = [hit,hit,hit],
R = 3 ;
X = 2,
L = [hit,hit],
R = 2 ;
X = 3,
L = [hit,hit,hit],
R = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
frequencies(Xs, Fs) :-
  msort(Xs,Sorted),
  glob( Sorted, [], Fs ).

glob( [], Fs, Fs ).
glob( [X|Xs], [X:N|Ts], Fs ) :-
  !,
  N1 is N+1,
  glob(Xs, [X:N1|Ts], Fs ).
glob( [X|Xs], Ts, Fs ) :-
  glob(Xs, [X:1|Ts], Fs).
```

That used `msort/2` to put the list in sequence.The resulting list is in descending sequence by key value — `[ 3:123, 2:25, 1:321 ]`.

You could also do something like this:

```
frequencies(Xs, Fs) :- frequencies( Xs, [], Fs ).

frequencies( [],     Fs, Fs ).
frequencies( [X|Xs], Ts, Fs ) :-
  tote( X, Ts, T1),
  frequencies(Xs, T1, Fs).

tote( X, Ts, Fs ) :-
  append( Pfx, [X:N|Sfx], Ts),
  !,
  N1 is N+1,
  append( Pfx, [X:N1|Sfx], Fs).
tote( X, Ts, [X:1|Ts] ).
```

I suspect that a one-time sort of the original list is probably going to be faster than repeated scans of the accumulator list.